# Select a specific group of nodes from xml tree - xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a hugely nested xml tree that I want to be able to query with xpath and only pick out selected nodes from each section of the tree.  For example in the following from each parent node i would like to get childTree > a and c > cb:

```
<parents>
    <parent>
      <childTree>
        <a></a>
        <b></b>
        <c>
          <ca></ca>
          <cb></cb>
        </c>
      </childTree>
    </parent>
    <parent>
      <childTree>
        <a></a>
        <b></b>
        <c>
          <ca></ca>
          <cb></cb>
        </c>
      </childTree>
    </parent>
    <parent>
      <childTree>
        <a></a>
        <b></b>
        <c>
          <ca></ca>
          <cb></cb>
        </c>
      </childTree>
    </parent>
<parents>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you? In Xpath you can use '|' as a union and do something like this:

```
//childTree/a|//childTree/c/cb
```

Comment: Hi Mike - no that doesnt give me the results I require I have tried it already.  Well, it does and doesnt.  It gives me the correct nodes but they are all seperate xml objects because the and operater is treating  the query as seperate queries.  I need a single object returned

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Mike - i want exactly the same structure minus the nodes that are not relevent i.e. the same structure containing the nodes I listed

Comment: @David: I'm not sure if XPath is the best tool to get the result you want (and if it even can be achieved). That kind of things are rather done by parsing XML and removing certain nodes in my opinion.

Comment: @David: XPath is a *query* language for XML documents -- it cannot modify the structure and or value of the document or of any nodes. Therefore, what you want isn't possible with XPath. You need to use another technology, such as XSLT, which is especially designed to transform XML documents.